# Firefox form submitting into newly created window

Tags: javascript, forms, firefox, window.open

I am having a small form and a small javascript that is working on every browser. Only firefox is having a problem executing that code correctly. Firefox is opening two windows.

Below the code:

The form:

```
<form name="TestName" class="smallform" action="myActionUrl.php" method="post" target="myTestWindowID" rel="noopener" style="display: none">
    <input type="hidden" name="aValue" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="bValue">
    <input type="hidden" name="cValue">
</form>
```

The JS Code:

```
document.myform.aValue.value = 1;
document.myform.bValue.value = 2;
document.myform.cValue.value = '3';
document.myform.target = 'myTestWindowID'

var popup = window.open('#', 'myTestWindowID', 'width=600,height=600,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,copyhistory=no');

document.myform.submit();
return false;
```

The behaviour in chrome, IE and others are "normal".

- Step1: Opening a new window ID myTestWindowID
- Step2: Submitting the form into this window
- Finished

While firefox is opening a new "about:blank" window. The form submit then opens a new tab. So as user I always have to close the small window popup.

Is there a way to change the behaviour of firefox?

Comment: Isn't your form name should be `myform` instead of `TestName`?

Comment: Well no, the name of the form is not the target of itself. 
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp

Targets can be: _blank|_self|_parent|_top|framename 
And mine should be the FRAMENAME.